# catch Exception with add

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I wrote this statement in the main method 
the Exception will be in the (`GuaranteeYears`) so i put it in the try block.

First in the `main` I make a `Store` object and pass number 4 in parameter, in the `Store` class I will have a array called `arrProduct` that will have the length 4:

```
boolean flag1 = true;
while (flag1) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Ente GuaranteeYears");
        int GuaranteeYears=read.nextInt();

        StrongDevice s = new StrongDevice(code,type,price,Model,Capacity,GuaranteeYears); //the object

        flag1 = false;
        x.addProduct(s);
     }
```

and this is my add method

```
public boolean addProduct(Product p) {
    if(arrProduct.length==NumOfProduct)
        return false;

    arrProduct[NumOfProduct]=p;
    NumOfProduct++;
    return true;
}
```

My question is: when I make the object and add it to the array it gives me `NullPointerException` - why that happened?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I really know what is Null pointer Exception , but I don't know why its happened here ?

Comment: There aren't a million reasons for NPE to happen. Read the answer. You will find out why it happens and you can apply that to your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, the line which cause `NPE` is

```
x.addProduct(s);
```

Most likely this is caused by array `arrProduct` which is not initialized and cause `NPE` when it is being accessed.

To fix that, please verify that `arrProduct` is always correctly initialized at `Store` object creation.

Comment: @BSMN Can you please post the whole `Store` class?

Comment: yes thank you , I initialized the array as public , then I initialized it again in the constructor ! , its work now, thank you for the help

Comment: @BSMN You're welcome, I'm glad to help. Do not forget to upvote the correct answer(s) and select one as correct.